# What does this drop mean in "MongoDB Drops ACID"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

title: MongoDB Drops ACID

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/multi-document-transactions-in-mongodb

> MongoDB 4.0 will add support for multi-document transactions, making it the only database to combine the speed, flexibility, and power of the document model with ACID data integrity guarantees. Through snapshot isolation, transactions provide a globally consistent view of data, and enforce all-or-nothing execution to maintain data integrity

I understand that drop means delete,remove??

drop here means `support` ??

Comment: It's a pun. Back in the '60s we called taking LSD "dropping acid"; MongoDB twists that phrase to refer to their adding "ACID data integrity guarantees", which I presume is meaningful to database programmers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Drops" in this context normally means "removes", as you noted. But in certain phrases it can mean something like "arrives", such as "the next podcast episode drops on Wednesday". So you could read it as "ACID arrives in MongoDB" (which doesn't really make sense, since ACID integrity was already there).

In this case, it's mostly a pun on "to drop acid", meaning "to take LSD". It presumably derived from "dropping" a tablet on your tongue.